# Specific word that describes the "average cost of something"

Tags: meaning

I encountered a word while reading that is defined as: "the usual price for a thing/service." For example, in the sentence "100 dollars is the average price that is paid for that product/service," that word would replace "average price that is paid for that product/service.".

Comment: Unfortunately, I doubt that you'll find an elegant one-word answer; most of them (especially the ones that fit best) will be phrases or expressions.

Comment: "average cost" of something is the right way to say it.

Answer (score 19):

You may be looking for *the **going** rate*

Here *going* is used with this definition from [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/going)

> The **going** rate or the **going** salary is the usual amount of money that you expect to pay or receive for something.
> Synonyms: current, accepted, standard, usual

Comment: is "going price" really the "going expression", i.e. can you add "going" to any X to make it the "average X"?
 i would lead with "going rate"

Comment: *The going rate* is more common.

Comment: @TinfoilHat -ok. changed...

Comment: @loonquawl "Average" usually implies "mathematical mean" (average of 4, 4, and 1 is 3), while "going" almost always implies "most common" (three merchants successfully sell eggs for $4, $4, and $1 respectively, so $4 is the going rate).  Additionally, "going" implies that a number is determined by societal norms;  talking about the "going rainfall" would sound very strange because how much it rains isn't a matter of other people's opinions.  It relates to the term "go through with" ("accept"/"agree to engage with") - a "going X" is an X that can be expected to "go through" a restriction.

Answer (score 18):

[Market rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Market_rate) should be fine, also.

> The market rate (or "going rate") for goods or services is the usual price charged for them in a free market.

e.g.;

> I need flour and I'm willing to pay over market rate for quick delivery.

Answer (score 1):

> A word that means, if you say something like "100 dollars is the average price that is paid for that product/service" Then that word would replace "is the average price that is paid for that product".

100 dollars **normally/usually**

Seeing that the word needs to have the elements, *single word*, *average*, and *a purchase*, **normally** or **usually** would be a single word that implies an average and allows the "100 dollars" to be suggestive towards a purchase in the right context.

Comment: Or... "typical"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the expression

***current price***

> the price at which something is selling at the present time.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: Whilst this does convey the temporal part of the requirement, it doesn't _necessarily_ mean the average price - sellers may all have different current prices.

Comment: @TobySpeight - yes and similarly the product may have different going prices.

Comment: Not easily - the term _going rate_ implies consensus, which this doesn't.

Comment: @TobySpeight - consensus limited in time and space. It is just an informal version of current price. But this is more about economics rather than language.

Comment: In language, the term "going rate" for something is the typical, standard, or usual price for that thing that a person would expect to see. Current price refers to a specific time, but has nothing to say about location or market, and could refer to the current price on average over the entire world, or could be the current price at one store. The current price may be drastically higher than the usual price, so this really doesn't answer the question as it is asked.

Answer (score 0):

This is the "recommended retail price" or "[list price](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_price)" or "(manufacturer's) suggested retail price". (The phrases here are given in the article I link to.)

Comment: These terms have a very different meaning than average price.  E.g., there's no such thing as an MSRP for a haircut.